# Datastax c# driver not returning row data

Tags: c#, cassandra

I have a simple column family with a single row of data in it.  Here is CQL Shell results when the table is queried:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 3.1.6 | Cassandra 1.2.8 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.0]

cqlsh:system> use cache

cqlsh:cache> SELECT locationid, payload FROM yellowbotcache;

 locationid | payload
------------+------------------
  f~123456x | This is a test 3

cqlsh:cache>
```

Here is the C# code that was used to insert the table data and then query for the row:

```
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
        using (Session sess = cluster.Connect())
        {
            sess.Execute("INSERT INTO cache.yellowbotcache (locationid, payload) VALUES ('f~123456x', 'This is a test 3');");

            RowSet result = sess.Execute("SELECT locationid,payload FROM cache.yellowbotcache WHERE locationid = 'f~123456x';");
            var rows = result.GetRows();
            if (rows.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    string payLoad = row.GetValue<string>("payload");
                }
            }
        }
```

Rows returns a single row with a length = 0.  The payload = ... statement results in an 'index out of bounds' error.  If I change locationid to an incorrect value the query does not return any rows.

Any ideas as to what is happening here?  I downloaded Cassandra and the driver from the DataStax site last week.

Comment: what happens when you take the `WHERE locationid = 'f~123456x'` constraint off the query?  That location id is funny enough that perhaps it has some reserved characters that the engine cant parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the data twice. First when you call `rows.Count() > 0` and then during iteration.

Once executed and iterated the Rows pseudo-collection is invalid. Therefore the simplest solution for you is to copy all results into the list first.

Try this,

```
var rows = rowSet.GetRows().ToList();
```

And now iterate over the list.